# What does "Wrap to beginning when end is reached" means?

Tags: java, replace

I've found that tooltip text in [jsyntaxpane's](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/) find/replace operation. However, I don't understand what that means, or how it should perform. I think it should do a replace, and if it reaches the end of the document it should stop there, it shouldn't go back at the beginning. However, it still goes at the beginning of the document. Has anyone encountered this concept before?

Comment: Most text editors work like this, but you can normally turn the wrapping behaviour off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is common. The purpose of this, is to search the entire document, when you are starting from somewhere in the middle.

Suppose you don't start your search from the beginning, but still want to search the entire document, this is the best way to easily do it.

Comment: however, no matter if I check the checkbox or not, I still get the same behaviour. The whole document is searched and replaced.